# Can gdb set a breakpoint on a tsan-detected race condition?

Tags: c++, gdb, thread-sanitizer

I am testing some code using Google's tsan thread sanitizer.  Tsan is telling me that I have a race condition in a particular function, but it is not clear to me from looking at the output what the problem is.  Is it possible to set a breakpoint in gdb to break on the spot where tsan generates the warning?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on `__tsan::PrintReport`?

Comment: Thanks, that's just the sort of thing I was looking for.  In my case the breakpoint never hit.  I tried looking for PrintReport in the tsan source code (https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerDevelopment), but could not find it.

Comment: You can find PrintReport [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/7a6461fcc2ed8e28c43993c561721af0bbe97f3a/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_report.cpp#L316).